# What is the max length of names in Blender?

Tags: python, materials, node-editor, shape-keys

Is there any max char length of names in Blender? I'm storing node names, material names, shape key names etc in a DB and need to setup the proper max length of the DB char fields.

Answer (score 1):

A test suggests that the longest name that an object can have is sixty one characters. I determined this by using the default cube, and giving it the name

> howlongof_anamecant_hiscubeob_jecthavea_nywayaques_tionerasks_a

A material name has the same parameters, leading me to suspect that the same name length is the default for any internal name.

Although you did not ask it, I believe that the total path name of a Blender file is OS dependent, and in Window 7 Professonal 64 bit, is about 256 characters.